# clojure.test throws? not working in the repl

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Following the docstring in the source of `clojure.test`, I issue the following in the repl:

```
(use 'clojure.test)
(is (thrown? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0)))
```

And other variations like substituting *ArithmeticException* with *java.lang.ArithmeticException*. Yet the exception is never captured by clojure.test but rather bubbles up all the way to the top:

```
> #error {  :cause "Divide by zero"  :via  [{:type java.lang.ArithmeticException    :message "Divide by zero"    :at
> [clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 158]}]  :trace 
> [[clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 158]  
> [clojure.lang.Numbers divide "Numbers.java" 3808]   [api.core$eval1305
> invokeStatic "form-init8750388124499546857.clj" 1]  
> [api.core$eval1305 invoke "form-init8750388124499546857.clj" 1]  
> [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 6927]  
> [clojure.lang.Compiler eval "Compiler.java" 6890]   [clojure.core$eval
> invokeStatic "core.clj" 3105]   [clojure.core$eval invoke "core.clj"
> 3101]   [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408$fn__7411 invoke
> "main.clj" 240]   [clojure.main$repl$read_eval_print__7408 invoke
> "main.clj" 240]   [clojure.main$repl$fn__7417 invoke "main.clj" 258]  
> [clojure.main$repl invokeStatic "main.clj" 258]   [clojure.main$repl
> doInvoke "main.clj" 174]   [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java"
> 1523]  
> [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__667
> invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 87]   [clojure.lang.AFn applyToHelper
> "AFn.java" 152]   [clojure.lang.AFn applyTo "AFn.java" 144]  
> [clojure.core$apply invokeStatic "core.clj" 646]  
> [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ invokeStatic "core.clj" 1881]  
> [clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_ doInvoke "core.clj" 1881]  
> [clojure.lang.RestFn invoke "RestFn.java" 425]  
> [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate
> invokeStatic "interruptible_eval.clj" 85]  
> [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate invoke
> "interruptible_eval.clj" 55]  
> [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__712$fn__715
> invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 222]  
> [clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__707
> invoke "interruptible_eval.clj" 190]   [clojure.lang.AFn run
> "AFn.java" 22]   [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor runWorker
> "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 1142]  
> [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker run
> "ThreadPoolExecutor.java" 617]   [java.lang.Thread run "Thread.java"
> 745]]}
```

What might it be?
Other stuff from clojure.test does work in the repl as expected.

Version information:

> Leiningen 2.7.1 on Java 1.8.0_101 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

```
> nREPL server started on port 44025 on host 127.0.0.1 -
> nrepl://127.0.0.1:44025 REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12 Clojure 1.8.0 Java
> HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_101-b13
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like the docstring at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html needs to be fixed then doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use it/wrap it in `(clojure.test/`[deftest](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/deftest)`...)`

---

assuming:

```
(require '[clojure.test :as t])
```

pass example

```
(t/deftest a 
  (t/testing "a test" 
    (t/is (thrown? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0)))))

(a)
nil
```

fail example

```
(t/deftest a 
  (t/testing "a test" 
    (t/is (thrown? NullPointerException (/ 1 0)))))

(a)
; ERROR in (a) (Numbers.java:158)
; a test
; expected: (thrown? NullPointerException (/ 1 0))
; actual: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero
```

you can also use `t/run-tests` to get a summary/stats

---

alternatively it seems you can use `t/test-var` directly like so

```
(t/test-var (t/is (thrown? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0))))
nil
```

Comment: I wonder why this has to be done. Might the docstring at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html require some improvement to avoid such misunderstanding?

Comment: @matanster  well, because only in test-var there is an actual try-catch

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in the `throws?` macro
 [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).  It is more versatile and
easier to use than the `thrown?` clause from `clojure.test`.  Note that `thrown?` in `clojure.test` is not a normal
Clojure function or macro, but is a custom expression recognized only within the `is` macro).

The `tupelo.test/throws?` macro is a normal Clojure macro that can be used anywhere.

`throws?` is meant to be used alone, and should not be wrapped within an `is` statement.
Note that `throws?` always returns either `true` or `false`, which can be used in further processing.

```
> lein repl
user=> (use 'tupelo.test)
user=> (throws?  (/ 1 0))
true    ; <= return value

user=> (throws? Exception (/ 1 0))
true    ; <= return value

user=> (throws? ArithmeticException (/ 1 0))
true    ; <= return value
```

If the expression does not thrown an exception, or thows a different type of exception, then
`throws?` will register a failed test via `(clojure.test/is false)`, and will also return `false`:

```
user=> (throws? NullPointerException (/ 1 0))
FAIL in () (form-init2868942318552383212.clj:1)
expected: (try (/ 1 0) false (catch NullPointerException t1__13775__auto__ true) (catch java.lang.Throwable t2__13776__auto__ false))
  actual: false
false   ; <= return value

clj.core=> (throws? ArithmeticException (+ 1 0))
FAIL in () (form-init4299343763551622058.clj:1)
expected: (try (+ 1 0) false (catch ArithmeticException t1__13761__auto__ true) (catch java.lang.Throwable t2__13762__auto__ false))
  actual: false
false    ; <= return value

clj.core=> (throws? (+ 1 0))
FAIL in () (form-init4299343763551622058.clj:1)
expected: (try (+ 1 0) false (catch java.lang.Throwable t3__13763__auto__ true))
  actual: false
false    ; <= return value
```

A typical usage of `throws?` is illustrated by tupelo.core's own unit tests:

```
(ns test.tupelo.core
  (:use clojure.test tupelo.test )
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(deftest t-grab
  (let [map1  {:a 1 :b 2}]
    (is= 1    (grab :a map1))
    (is= 2    (grab :b map1))
    (throws?  (grab :c map1)) ))
```

Comment: Hello Alan, you’re always enthusiastic about sharing Tupelo here. Nothing wrong with that, but I think it would be good to disclose that you’re the author. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior